# Docker's iptables=false option seems to have not the desired behavior

Tags: iptables, docker, ufw

Good morning at all. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 server and Docker 1.8.1 and UFW is my front-end to manage iptables.

I need to run an application into a container. I do need the following behavior:

- my app need to connect to another machine on port, to say, 8888/tcp.
- I do not want that docker manages my iptables, hence i have set `DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"` in `/etc/default/docker`.
  That done, docker should now skip to set **ANY** iptables rule.

Then, i have done the following in UFW in order to get docker containers connect to the outside world:

- set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` in `/etc/default/ufw`
- set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

I have also added the following lines to `/etc/ufw/before.rules` to enable NAT functionalities:

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from private network through eth0, the Internet iface on master.
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.42.1/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

where `172.17.42.1/16` is the docker iface ip range.

After a reboot, i have ran `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n`, which gives me:

```
[....]
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
```

Then, since my `DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY` is set to `DROP`, and i wanted to test whether the `iptables=false` option actually works, i have ran:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 bash
root@56997560933c:/# apt-get update
```

**but..the container is able to download updates, even if the port 80/tcp and 53 are not open to the outside on the host machine..**

I am know wondering...what i did wrong? what more i have to do in order to avoid that a docker container connects to the outside world using a port that i **have not allowed** in my iptables (using UFW) ?

THANK YOU.

**Note for completeness:**
There are no traces of DOCKER in any chain in my iptables. Also, when downloading updates, if i run `netstat` , there are no ESTABLISHED connections outside ssh...this is even stranger...

reported from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307821/get-docker-working-with-ufw-and-iptables-false-option) of another user, posted on stackoverflow. I think this is the right place.

Comment: So are you Alberto or do you just have exactly the same problem? :)

Comment: No i'm not alberto.. but i had a similar problem that i have not solved yet and i am in general interested in docker networking :) I have also upvoted his question

Comment: Show the complete firewall.